# Neither .bashrc nor .profile gets read when bash is set as the shell in macOS 11

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm

I know macOS 11 is trying hard to convince me to use `zsh`, but it also says I can choose another shell, which I have: `chsh -s /bin/bash`. The problem is, it no longer works as it did, as it neither reads my `.profile` nor my `.bashrc` when I start `Terminal.app` or `iTerm.app`. I just get this:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$
```

If I now manually type `bash`, things happen as they should:

```
bash-3.2$ bash
[Timer is unset. Use timer_start] core utils setup finished
[3] Executing $HOME/.bashrc
[7] Reading utility functions and aliases
[10] core utils setup finished
[14] Reading aliases and functions
[22] ssh aliases
[26] conversions
[30] Use htop if available
[36] small utils and aliases
[40] aliases: setting up node aliases
[44] aliases: finished setting up node aliases
[48] webserver aliases
[52] global aliases and functions finished
[56] Reading utils for git prompt
[63] Reading bash completion files
[69] /Users/carlerik/.bash_completion.d/azure
[75] /Users/carlerik/.bash_completion.d/git
[89] /Users/carlerik/.bash_completion.d/npm
[95] /Users/carlerik/.bash_completion.d/tmux
[100] Reading color codes
[105] Read /Users/carlerik/.bash.d/colors
[130] Read /Users/carlerik/bin/z.sh
[135] Reading local settings for this machine
[140] Load personalized bashrc for mac
[152] Read /Users/carlerik/.bashrc.local
This setup is missing 'direnv'. Please install it for per-directory overrides
[157] Finished bash setup
[205] Read /Users/carlerik/.secret

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

carlerik at idas-imac in ~
$
```

All the timing stuff is due to a `DEBUG` setting I have enabled (my [`.bashrc`](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/common-setup/bashrc) in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles)). So it works as normal.

**How can I get macOS 11 to use my .bashrc and/or .profile on startup?**

I have even tried overriding the terminal settings in both apps from the standard logon shell to `/bin/bash --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc` with no further success (just as a temporary workaround to see if it was possible to force it to read my init files).

For reference, this is my .profile:

```
printf "Reading .profile"
export DEBUG=1

if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# other stuff
# ...
# other stuff end

if [ -f "$HOME/.profile.local" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.profile.local"
fi
```

Comment: `/bin/bash --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc` is not a login shell so won't read ~/.profile but should read ~/.bashrc

Comment: Note that in the output from runing bash from the command line it correctly does not show the output of printf "Reading .profile". I would suggest there is a problem with your actual ~/.profile or have you got an empty ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login that bash sees first.

Comment: @mmmmmm: I only tried that to _force_ it to read the basrc, with no apparent effect. I also tried `--logon` to try and force a read of `.profile`, to no avail. Weird as hell.

Comment: Have you got either of the other r files I mentioned?

Comment: I missed that question, but I'll try to check when I get back from work. I have been quite diligent in removing those previously to mostly have settings in .profile that can be used in all shells, but maybe there have been files added by upgrading macOS 11? I doubt it, but worth checking out :)

Comment: Login shells never read .bashrc. To force a login shell, use `--login` (not `--logon`)

Comment: Also, did you change any of the related files in `/etc` in the past?

Comment: It was a typo - would probably get an error if I wrote it like that. And logon shells do not read .bashrc on their own, but if you look at my `.profile ` listed above, you will see that they do regardless ;)

Comment: No changing of `/etc` for bash, no

Comment: @mmmmmm You were right about the other r files! Installing the `gcloud` SDK automatically created a `.bash_profile`, thus overriding my .profile. Removing it immediately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this was hinted to by @mmmmmm: without my knowledge, a `.bash_profile` file had been added, thus making bash choose to read that instead of `.profile`.

The culprit was the installer script for `gcloud`, the CLI for the Google Cloud SDK.

For my cross-platform dotfiles, I have moved these mac-specific settings to [another file which is only read when using mac (in my setup)](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/81f8e23438ccc6d60fd2142525540ec0deb72024#diff-0f6b3737e437e88f57c7a3a25b5c29ca5834a721b10cd42e1fb23e23295944a0R13).

Comment: Or better use .bash_profile rather than .profil unless you do use sh or dash sometimes.

Comment: I use .profile because I use different shells at times. I keep most shell specific things in the rc file.

Comment: `gcloud` messed up my terminal prompt too, but there's no new profile script on my root. I know my `.zprofile` is being run but I cannot find what else it is calling to change the prompt!